# Why can't I use HttpWebRequest more than one despite KeepAlive equals true?

Tags: c#, webrequest, keep-alive

I am trying to use a HttpWebRequest made already to a source to get Content-Length and Resumeability. But It throws an error while doing this. I can't understand why it happens.

> **My code block**

```
public void checkUrl(ref long size, ref bool resumeable)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
    req.Accept = "*/*";
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 5;
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.Timeout = 10000;

    using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetHttpWebResponse())
       size = resp.ContentLength;


    req.AddRange(0, size / 2);
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetHttpWebResponse())
       resumeable = (resp.ContentLength == size / 2 + 1);

    req.Abort();
}
```

It throws an `ObjectDisposedException` on the second `using` statement and says `Cannot access a disposed object`. How I fix this situation?

Comment: Thanks @hoodaticus. It solved my problem. But I was thinking `using` statement closes and disposes the `HttpWebResponse`.

Comment: you can't use an object after it's disposed.  It is part of the interface contract for IDisposable that all calls to an implementing object must throw ObjectDisposedException if Dispose has been called (though everyone cheats and makes this silently fail as well).

Comment: But here we reuse only the `HttpWebRequest` and disposed object is `HttpWebResponse`. Do these two have a strong dependency enough to cause releasing `HttpWebRequest` when `HttpWebResponse` is disposed?

Comment: it's kind of intuitive that Request knows about the WebResponse since it has to retrieve it for you.  If you don't close your response between requests then the request is still holding onto the old one.